# How to avoid gcc warning in Python C extension when using Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS

Tags: python, gcc, gil, cextension

The simplest way to manipulate the GIL in Python C extensions is to use the macros provided:

```
my_awesome_C_function() 
{
    blah;

    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS

    // do stuff that doesn't need the GIL

    if (should_i_call_back) {
        Py_BLOCK_THREADS
        // do stuff that needs the GIL
        Py_UNBLOCK_THREADS
    }

    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

    return blah blah;
}
```

This works great, letting me release the GIL for the bulk of my code, but re-grabbing it for small bits of code that need it.

The problem is when I compile this with gcc, I get:

```
ext/engine.c:548: warning: '_save' might be used uninitialized in this function
```

because Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS is defined like this:

```
#define Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS { \
        PyThreadState *_save; \
        _save = PyEval_SaveThread();
```

So, three questions:

1. Is it possible to suppress gcc's warning,
2. Does anyone have any idea why gcc thinks `_save` might be used uninitialized, since it is assigned to immediately after its declaration, and
3. Why wouldn't the macro have been defined to declare and initialize the variable in one statement to avoid the issue?

(the last two are really just for my own curiosity).

I can avoid the issue by not using the macros and doing it all myself, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible to suppress uninitialized warnings using the -Wno- prefix.

`-Wall -Wno-uninitialized`

If you want to remove just this warning, you could simply initialize `_save` to a null pointer so that it doesn't rely on a function return value... that one line of code and a comment makes sense to me:

```
PyThreadState *_save; 
_save = 0; /* init as null pointer value */
_save = PyEval_SaveThread();
```

Comment: I was hoping for a very localized way to disable just this one warning on this line.  I'd rather not disable all uninitialized warnings.

Comment: if you want to prevent just this warning, add a line before you call `PyEval_SaveThread()` to initialize `_save` to a null pointer (see updated answer above)

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

1. You can suppress specific warnings, but I guess you already knew that.
2. It says *might* be uninitialized :-)
3. The only reason I can imagine is compatibility with older C compilers.

I tried digging into [the source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#3fD1GHAPH9Q/download/releases/src/python-2.0c1.tar.gz%7ChvkyD6N58ac/Python-2.0c1/Include/ceval.h&q=Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS&d=0), but couldn't find any good clues.

Comment: 1. I knew I could disable entire classes of warnings on the command line, but I was hoping for a pragma that could disable just this one warning.

Answer (score 0):

Ned, you can try [one of these](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wno-unitialized"
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wno-uninitialized"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wno-uninialized"
```

Or ignore `-Wuninitialized`? According to the documentation, you have to do this before any data or functions are defined. Maybe it will let you disable the warning just for that file?